# Parse error unexpected t_double_arrow what's wrong?

Tags: php

```
array_push($data, $_POST['username'] =>array("url" =>"uploadedfiles/" . $_FILES['file']['name'] ,"pass"=>$_POST['password']));
```

This is the line that the error occurs on, is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: There is a syntax error in your code. => can only be used under certain circumstances (array, foreach). What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can not do the way you are trying. If I understood you are setting $_POST["username"] with some array value and then pushing into an array and if so the correct way should be

```
$_POST['username'] = array
    (
        "url" =>"uploadedfiles/" . $_FILES['file']['name'] ,
        "pass"=>$_POST['password']
    );


array_push($data, $_POST['username']);
```

array_push is used to push element in existing array https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Here is an example how it works

```
$data =array("kk");


array_push($data, array("a","b"));

print_r($data);
```

output ::

```
Array ( [0] => kk [1] => Array ( [0] => a [1] => b ) )
```

Comment: Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Comment: what is ur $data array ? does it contain anything if not then u will get this error.

Comment: $data=array("user1"=>array("url"=>"user1.pphp","password"=>"pass1"), 
            "user2"=>array("url"=>"user2.php","password"=>"pass2"),
            "user3"=>array("url"=>"user3.php", "password"=>"pass3"));